# How to parse the Range object in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, qr-code

I need to parse and edit the Range object (result of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()`)in Google Apps Script.

**The Goal**: In Google Sheets: a user clicks an item (in Column A) and presses a button "Create QR Code" from the toolbar. This places a corresponding QR code later in the row (Column C).

I'm expecting something like (*pseudocode*):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
//Logger.log(cell) --> "A2"
cell = cell.split("");
cell[0] = "B";
cell = cell.join("")
//Logger.log(cell) --> "B2"
ss.getRange(cell).setFormula('=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="' + cell'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the range object is not recommended. Use [range.offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)) instead:

```
SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveRange()
    .offset(0,1)
    .setFormula('=1+0')
```